# create columns in existing table and populate data using procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I will try to keep the query as short as possible. This involves 2 tables - lets call them staging_data and audit_data. STAGING_DATA has 3 columns:

- user_no with data type number,
- update_date_time with data type as date in DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format
- status_code which is varchar(1).

audit_data table also has the same 3 columns. The ask is to add 3 columns to audit_data table

- seq_no (which will be unique to every user),
- active_from (date type without the time format)
- active_to (date type without the time format).

There is a procedure that inserts data from staging_data to audit_data.
Sample of the table audit_data

[image: staging_data]

That data in audit table should look like :

[image: Audit Data]

For the next record for user_no 523(lets assume update_date_time is '23-Nov-2020 10:20') seq_no becomes 3, active_from_date becomes '23-Nov-2020', active_to becomes 31-Dec-99 and the active_to of user_no 523 with seq_no 2 becomes '22-Nov-2020'. So the data should look like this :

[image: new record]

Highlighted the 3rd record which will be added later in light green.

So here goes my solution : I suggested to use `row_number() over(partition by user_no)` analytical function to get seq_no for each user. I wanted to create a view based on that but Boss doesn't want a view. He strictly wants to use a procedure. Procedure should check if the user_no exists (in this example 523). If exists then seq_no increases and active_to of the previous record for 523 changes to latest active_from - 1 date. I will be honest - I have no clue how to achieve this in Procedure. I understand I can create a cursor with the query I had in my mind for the view. But to add seq_no and change active_to date is something that has puzzled me. Can anyone please guide me in right direction/s? Also I apologise in advance if I have left out any other details. Its midnight here now and after 8 hours of racking my brain on this I am very hungry!

edit 11th Mar : here is the code for the procedure I wrote to insert data into the audit table for situation when a particular user_no has no record in audit table :

```
create or replace procedure test_aud IS
  user_found_audit number;
  lv_user_no AUDIT_DATA.user_no%TYPE;
  cursor member_no is select distinct user_no from STAGING_DATA;
begin
  open member_no;
  loop
    fetch member_no into lv_user_no;
    exit when member_no%notfound;
    select count(*) into user_found_audit from AUDIT_DATA where user_no = lv_user_no;
    if user_found_audit = 0 then
      insert into AUDIT_DATA(user_no, update_date_time,status_code, seq_no, last_update_date, active_from, active_to)
      select user_no, update_date_time,status_code,row_number() over(partition by user_no order by UPDATE_DATE_TIME) as seqno,
      to_char(trunc(update_date_time),'DD-MON-YYYY'),
      to_char(trunc(update_date_time),'DD-MON-YYYY'),
      lead(to_char(trunc(update_date_time)-1,'DD-MON-YYYY'),1,'31-DEC-99') over(PARTITION BY user_no ORDER BY UPDATE_DATE_TIME) from STAGING_DATA where user_no = lv_user_no;
      commit;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line(lv_user_no||' exists in audit table');
      -- to code the block when user_no exists, involves an update and insert
    end if;
        
  end loop;
  
  close member_no;
  
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to collect a couple things. The latest stage row and the latest audit row. Then it is just a matter of generating the new audit information and updating the previous latest one. The following makes a couple simplifying assumptions:

1. Only the latest stage data for a given user_no needs processed as
   all prior have been processed, However it does not assume the stage
   table has been cleared.
2. The sequencing of 'Y' and 'N' status_codes are properly order in
   that manner. In fact it does not even check the value.
3. It need not concern itself with the inherent race condition. The
   condition is derives from seq_no being generated as Max()+1. This
   structure virtually guarantees a duplicate will eventually be
   created.

The nested procedure "establish_audit" does all the actual work. The rest are just supporting characters, including a couple just for debug purpose.  See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9e803a35ccaa29fb675dcec4231025b).

```
create or replace 
procedure generate_stage_audit(user_no_in staging_data.user_no%type) 
as 
    k_end_of_time constant date := date '9999-12-31'; 
    l_latest_user_stage staging_data%rowtype;
    l_latest_user_audit audit_data%rowtype;  
    
    procedure establish_audit
    is 
    begin
       insert into audit_data(user_no, update_date_time, status_code 
                             ,seq_no, active_from, active_to)                     
           select l_latest_user_stage.user_no
                , l_latest_user_stage.update_date_time
                , l_latest_user_stage.status_code
                , coalesce(l_latest_user_audit.seq_no,0) + 1
                , trunc(l_latest_user_stage.update_date_time)               
                , k_end_of_time
             from dual;
              
       update audit_data 
          set active_to = trunc(l_latest_user_stage.update_date_time - 1)
         where user_no = l_latest_user_audit.user_no 
           and seq_no  = l_latest_user_audit.seq_no; 
    end establish_audit;
    
    procedure retrieve_latest_stage
    is 
    begin
        select * 
          into l_latest_user_stage
          from staging_data  
         where (user_no,  update_date_time) =
               ( select user_no,  max(update_date_time)
                   from staging_data                  
                  where user_no = user_no_in
                  group by user_no
               );    
    end retrieve_latest_stage; 
    
    procedure retrieve_latest_audit
    is 
    begin
        select * 
         into l_latest_user_audit
         from audit_data  
        where (user_no, seq_no) =
              ( select user_no,  max(seq_no)
                  from audit_data             
                 where user_no = user_no_in
                 group by user_no
              );
    exception
      when no_data_found then 
           null;           
    end retrieve_latest_audit;  
        
    ---- for debugging ---   
    procedure show_stage 
    is 
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line('-------- Stage Row -------');
        dbms_output.put_line('         user_no==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_stage.user_no));
        dbms_output.put_line('update_date_time==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_stage.update_date_time));
        dbms_output.put_line('     status_code==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_stage.status_code));
    end show_stage;
   
    procedure show_audit 
    is 
    begin 
        dbms_output.put_line('-------- Audit Row -------');
        dbms_output.put_line('         user_no==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.user_no));
        dbms_output.put_line('update_date_time==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.update_date_time));
        dbms_output.put_line('     status_code==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.status_code));
        dbms_output.put_line('          seq_no==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.seq_no));      
        dbms_output.put_line('     active_from==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.active_from)); 
        dbms_output.put_line('       active_to==>' || to_char(l_latest_user_audit.active_to));      
    end show_audit;
 
begin  -- the main event
    retrieve_latest_stage;
    show_stage; 
    
    retrieve_latest_audit; 
    show_audit;
   
    establish_audit; 
end generate_stage_audit;
```

A couple warnings:

- It seems you may be tempted to use string data type for the audit
  columns Active_Form and Active_to as you are trying to declare then
  "date type without the time". However there is no such data type in
  Oracle; time is part of all dates. **Do not** do so, store them as
  standard dates. (Note Dates are not stored in any format, but an
  internal structure. Formats are strictly a visual representation).
  Just throwaway the time with the format on the query or by setting
  nls_date_format.
- You may be tempted to convert call this through a trigger. **Do not**,
  it will likely result in an "ORA-04091: Table is mutating"
  exception.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I am getting compiled with errors. After declaring 2 rowtypes dont we have to declare a cursor for each one?

Comment: By the way I wrote a procedure for a situation when there is no data for a particular user_no present in audit_data table : ok getting an error while pasting the code for procedure. Anyone know any option to post my code in comment? Or shall I edit my question?

Comment: Edit the question. Do not post code in the as comment (1 line generally ok).  Further saying you are getting a compile or otherwise is *completely useless*. What is needed is  the specifics: exact error and location.  Same with "does not work". There post results and description of why it is wrong. In either case you may want to post a comment indicating you have updated the question.